# I have a button and I only want it to be pressed with a left click not enter key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button in my site which is a simple aim trainer and you should click the button with left click. Everything works like a charm but if you click the button and hold it, then you hold enter, you can click 303 times in 10secs and that is cheating. I want it to only be pressed with left click. Explain your answer please.

Link to the site: https://mfa-aim-trainer.netlify.app

```js
var b = document.querySelector("button");
var score = document.getElementById('score');
var counter = 0;
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
var tensec = document.getElementById("10sec");
var pxs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
var scr = document.getElementById("scr");
var mis = document.getElementById("mis");
var htm = document.getElementById("htm");
var missc = 0;
var height1 = 100;
var width1 = 100;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("theLeftSide");
var resetbtn = document.getElementById("reset");
var vr = document.getElementById("vr");
var hit = 1080;
var fontsize = 25;
var ulcls = document.getElementsByClassName("theul");
var ul = document.getElementById('10sec');
var best = document.getElementById("best");
var cntrspn = document.getElementsByClassName("cntrspn");
var lists = document.getElementsByClassName("lists");

b.addEventListener("click", change);
b.addEventListener("click", plus);
htm.addEventListener("click", miss);
pxs[0].addEventListener("click", plussize);
pxs[1].addEventListener("click", minesize);
theLeftSide.addEventListener("click", leftsclick);
b.addEventListener("click", misscmines);
resetbtn.addEventListener("click", resetall);

function plussize() {
  height1 += 10;
  width1 += 10;
  missc++
  missc + 1
  missc--
  fontsize += 3;

  b.style.fontSize = fontsize + "px";
  b.style.height = height1 + "px";
  b.style.width = width1 + "px";
  missc - 1;
}

function minesize() {
  height1 -= 10;
  width1 -= 10;
  missc++
  missc + 1
  missc--
  fontsize -= 3;

  b.style.fontSize = fontsize + "px";
  b.style.height = height1 + "px";
  b.style.width = width1 + "px";
  missc - 1;
}

function miss() {
  missc++
  mis.innerHTML = missc - counter;

}


setInterval(function() {
  var misc = missc - counter;
  ul.style.height = window.offsetheight;

  var currscr = counter;


  for (var i = 0; i < cntrspn.length; i += 1) {

    if (parseInt(scr.textContent) > parseInt(best.textContent)) {
      best.textContent = scr.textContent;
    } else {
      console.log("no new best");
    }
  }


  mis.textContent = missc - counter;

  ul.innerHTML += '<li class="lists">' + '<span class="cntrspn">' + counter + '</span>' + "-" + misc + '</li>';

  missc = 0;
  misc = 0;
  counter = 0;
  scr.textContent = counter;
  mis.textContent = missc;


}, 10000);


function change() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 1;
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 1;
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * -1100) + 1;

  b.style.padding = 0 + "px";
  b.style.left = i + "px";
  b.style.top = j + "px";
  b.style.right = r + "px";

}

function plus() {
  missc--
  missc - 1
  counter++;
  scr.textContent = counter;

}

function leftsclick() {
  missc--
  missc - 1
}

function misscmines() {
  missc++
  missc + 1
}

function resetall() {
  window.location.reload(true);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.btndiv {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 1724px;
  position: fixed;
  user-select: none;
}

.sizes {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  user-select: none;
}

.score {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none
}

.shr7 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  left: 100px;
  color: white;
  left: 49%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  user-select: none
}

.allcont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(25, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.theLeftSide {
  width: 190px;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  border-right: 6px solid #464646;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.theul {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  border-right: solid 6px #464646;
  display: block;
}

li {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  user-select: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="htm" style="font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace; user-select: none;">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons\icon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aimcss.css">


  <div class="btndiv"><button id="btn" class="btn"><b>Click me</b></button></div>

  <div id="theLeftSide" class="theLeftSide">
    <div id="pxs" class="sizes div">+ 10px</div>
    <div id="pxs" class="sizes div">- 10px</div>

    <div class="allcont">
      <p id="score" class="score">score:
        <p id="scr" class="score">0</p>
      </p>
      <title>Aim trainer</title>

    </div>

    <div class="allcont">
      <p id="misses" class="score">misses:
        <p id="mis" class="score">0</p>
      </p>
    </div>

    <br onscroll="func()">

    <div class="allcont" id="bestdiv">
      <p class="score">Best:
        <p class="score" id="best">0</p>
      </p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div style=" padding-left: 5px;"><button style="height: 30px; width: 70px; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;" id="reset"><b>RESET</b></button></div>

    <br><br>

    <p type="inherit" class="shr7">• Score-Misses</p>

    <ol start="1" id='10sec' class='theul'>
      <li style="display: none;" class="lists"><span class="cntrspn">0</span>-0</li>
    </ol>

  </div>


</head>


<body id="bod" style="background-color: #181818;">




  <script type="text/javascript" src="aimscript.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code; a plain `missc + 1` or `missc - 1;` does nothing. Oddly, you have correctly used `+=` and `-=` and `++`, `--` above or below it. The really invalid thing is all of the HTML you have in the `head`, which should be in the `body`. `title`, `meta`, and `link` elements go in `head`; a few others are allowed. `div`, `br`, `ol`, all are invalid in the `head`, but are welcome in the `body`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey so i should move everything from the ```<head>```  tag to the ```<body>``` except the ```<meta> , <title> , <link>``` elements ? and what is the difference because it did nothing

Comment: Yes move everything except those elements to the `body`. Browsers have to deal with people giving them all kinds of invalid crap and they've got to do what they can with it. You can make their jobs easy or you can make them hard. The reward for making it easy on the browser is faster load times (better performance). I didn't say it would fix the problem your question is about (in fact, I purposefully used a comment because it was not an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend checking the `event.pointerId` variable when the click occurs.

```js
b.addEventListener('click', change);

const change = (event) => {
    if(event.pointerId === -1) {
        // this is a "keyboard click" that you want to avoid
    }
    else {
        // actual click
    }
};
```

When the mouse is used, the `pointerId` should be non-negative. When the keyboard is used to "click," the ID will be -1.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to stop an edge case where users can hold down enter and the left mouse button as they will keep scoring.

I would recommend listening for the enter key using the keydown and keyup events to track when enter is pressed then using the state to disable any logic while it is pressed.

```js
let isEnterPressed = false

window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if(e.keyCode === 13) 
    isEnterPressed = true // 13 is keycode for enter
})

window.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if(e.keyCode === 13) 
    isEnterPressed = false // 13 is keycode for enter
})
```

then just use isEnterPressed to block any logic triggered by clicking.

This is just a simple example, you could generalize this to track any keyboard input

Comment: The "hack" is also possible using the space bar, not just the Enter key. There may be other ways to trigger it too.

Comment: Yeah I was just answering the scope of the question, @callmenikk could just check if any key is pressed while clicking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keypress` listener on the button and `preventDefault()` when the enter triggers on the button `priventDefault()` will stop that

```js
var b = document.querySelector("button");
var score = document.getElementById('score');
var counter = 0;
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
var tensec = document.getElementById("10sec");
var pxs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
var scr = document.getElementById("scr");
var mis = document.getElementById("mis");
var htm = document.getElementById("htm");
var missc = 0;
var height1 = 100;
var width1 = 100;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("theLeftSide");
var resetbtn = document.getElementById("reset");
var vr = document.getElementById("vr");
var hit = 1080;
var fontsize = 25;
var ulcls = document.getElementsByClassName("theul");
var ul = document.getElementById('10sec');
var best = document.getElementById("best");
var cntrspn = document.getElementsByClassName("cntrspn");
var lists = document.getElementsByClassName("lists");

b.addEventListener("click", change);
b.addEventListener("click", plus);
htm.addEventListener("click", miss);
pxs[0].addEventListener("click", plussize);
pxs[1].addEventListener("click", minesize);
theLeftSide.addEventListener("click", leftsclick);
b.addEventListener("click", misscmines);
resetbtn.addEventListener("click", resetall);

function plussize() {
  height1 += 10;
  width1 += 10;
  missc++
  missc + 1
  missc--
  fontsize += 3;

  b.style.fontSize = fontsize + "px";
  b.style.height = height1 + "px";
  b.style.width = width1 + "px";
  missc - 1;
}

function minesize() {
  height1 -= 10;
  width1 -= 10;
  missc++
  missc + 1
  missc--
  fontsize -= 3;

  b.style.fontSize = fontsize + "px";
  b.style.height = height1 + "px";
  b.style.width = width1 + "px";
  missc - 1;
}

function miss() {
  missc++
  mis.innerHTML = missc - counter;

}


setInterval(function() {
  var misc = missc - counter;
  ul.style.height = window.offsetheight;

  var currscr = counter;


  for (var i = 0; i < cntrspn.length; i += 1) {

    if (parseInt(scr.textContent) > parseInt(best.textContent)) {
      best.textContent = scr.textContent;
    } else {
      console.log("no new best");
    }
  }


  mis.textContent = missc - counter;

  ul.innerHTML += '<li class="lists">' + '<span class="cntrspn">' + counter + '</span>' + "-" + misc + '</li>';

  missc = 0;
  misc = 0;
  counter = 0;
  scr.textContent = counter;
  mis.textContent = missc;


}, 10000);


function change(e) {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 1;
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 1;
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * -1100) + 1;

  b.style.padding = 0 + "px";
  b.style.left = i + "px";
  b.style.top = j + "px";
  b.style.right = r + "px";

}

function plus() {
  missc--
  missc - 1
  counter++;
  scr.textContent = counter;

}

function leftsclick() {
  missc--
  missc - 1
}

function misscmines() {
  missc++
  missc + 1
}

function resetall() {
  window.location.reload(true);
}

b.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
  let key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  
  if (key == 13) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

button{
  outline: none;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.btndiv {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 1724px;
  position: fixed;
  user-select: none;
}

.sizes {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  user-select: none;
}

.score {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none
}

.shr7 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  left: 100px;
  color: white;
  left: 49%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  user-select: none
}

.allcont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(25, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.theLeftSide {
  width: 190px;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  border-right: 6px solid #464646;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.theul {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  border-right: solid 6px #464646;
  display: block;
}

li {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  user-select: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="htm" style="font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace; user-select: none;">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons\icon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aimcss.css">


  <div class="btndiv"><button id="btn" class="btn"><b>Click me</b></button></div>

  <div id="theLeftSide" class="theLeftSide">
    <div id="pxs" class="sizes div">+ 10px</div>
    <div id="pxs" class="sizes div">- 10px</div>

    <div class="allcont">
      <p id="score" class="score">score:
        <p id="scr" class="score">0</p>
      </p>
      <title>Aim trainer</title>

    </div>

    <div class="allcont">
      <p id="misses" class="score">misses:
        <p id="mis" class="score">0</p>
      </p>
    </div>

    <br onscroll="func()">

    <div class="allcont" id="bestdiv">
      <p class="score">Best:
        <p class="score" id="best">0</p>
      </p>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div style=" padding-left: 5px;"><button style="height: 30px; width: 70px; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;" id="reset"><b>RESET</b></button></div>

    <br><br>

    <p type="inherit" class="shr7">• Score-Misses</p>

    <ol start="1" id='10sec' class='theul'>
      <li style="display: none;" class="lists"><span class="cntrspn">0</span>-0</li>
    </ol>

  </div>


</head>


<body id="bod" style="background-color: #181818;">




  <script type="text/javascript" src="aimscript.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```